# How To Use Query Inside Django Model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I Have 2 Different Django Model User_detials and Monthly_payment and now I want to make the **Status= Active, Expire, Soon Expire, or Deactivated**, in User details i am trying this but not work ho to make using 2 different model different fields using username  and received date is any solution ?? here is my model

```
class Client_Detials(models.Model, object):
    First_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Contact_1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Contact_2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Email = models.EmailField()
    Username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    cont_type = (
        ('Fiber', 'Fiber'),
        ('wireless', 'wireless'),
    )
    Connection_Type = models.CharField(choices=cont_type, max_length=12, default='Fiber')
    Internet_Plan = models.ForeignKey(Nas_Package, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Payment_Cycle = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    User_Img = models.ImageField(upload_to='Client', default='user.jpg', blank=True)
    Created_by = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Created_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        def status(self):
        recharge = recharge_monthly.username
        if recharge == self.Username:
            date_to_re = recharge_monthly.received_date
            myd = datetime.datetime.now().date() - date_to_re
            print(myd)
            if myd.days < 20:
                return "Active"
            elif myd.days < 25:
                return "Expire Soon"
            elif myd.days <= 30:
                return "Expire"
            else:
                return "Expire From {} day".format(30 - myd.days)



class recharge_monthly(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(Client_Detials, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Total_amount = models.FloatField()
    Received_amount = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    received_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_vat_add = models.BooleanField()
    is_tsc_add = models.BooleanField()
    tsc_amount = models.FloatField()
    vat_amount = models.FloatField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can be wrong, but it seems to me that you are trying to access a related recharge_monthly object in your Client_details model. If this is what you really want, here's the solution.

I suggest you add a parameter to the `username` field, like:

```
class recharge_monthly(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(Client_Detials, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='recharges')
```

After this, you will be able to access all the related objects in the parent model. Then, in `def status()`:

```
@property
def status(self):
    recharge = self.recharges.last()
    date_to_re = recharge.received_date
    myd = datetime.datetime.now().date() - date_to_re
    if myd.days < 20:
        return "Active"
    elif myd.days < 25:
        return "Expire Soon"
    elif myd.days <= 30:
        return "Expire"
    else:
        return "Expire From {} day".format(30 - myd.days)
```

Here we define, that in the `Client_Details` model we will be able to access all the related `recharge_monthly` objects. In the `status` function we get the last created `recharge_monthly` object and we return a status depending on how long ago this object was created. The `@property` decorator makes this function act like property, it will be convenient because the `status` function now becomes the only place where we can find the truth about the object state.

I'm also not sure if you exactly know what you are doing here, and how it needs to be done. This part of code can do stuff to make it work a little, but I am totally not sure about what the question is about. I will be glad if you explain to me more so we can move forward and choose the right solution.

Comment: Thanks, Pending Finalizer its seen like work how to used latest date for check